# How to display comment thread hierarchy in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, json

I have a set of comments in JSON.
This JSON is loaded into a browser.
I wish to display the comments as a threaded comment hierarchy, with the most recent comment first.
I've done lots of searching to find the right algorithm.  Surely this is a solved problem but I can't find it.

To explain the JSON fields:

- createdtime = epochseconds (the time the comment was created)
- documentid = the documentid of this comment
- parentdocumentid = the documentid of the comment that this comment is a reply to
- topleveldocumentid = documentid of the blog post that the comments
  belong to

The question is, what is an effective way to display these comments in HTML as a hierarchy using Javascript? (Jquery code is fine)

```
[
    {
        "commenttext": "This is a comment",
        "parentdocumentid": "c88cbdd6d05811e19fe912314301329d",
        "doctype": "comment",
        "topleveldocumentid": "c88cbdd6d05811e19fe912314301329d",
        "createdtime": 1343222535,
        "documentid": "c0341e96d65b11e1a91d12314301329d"
    },
    {
        "commenttext": "This is a another comment",
        "parentdocumentid": "c88cbdd6d05811e19fe912314301329d",
        "doctype": "comment",
        "topleveldocumentid": "c88cbdd6d05811e19fe912314301329d",
        "createdtime": 1343222639,
        "documentid": "fe5209e0d65b11e1a91d12314301329d"
    },
    {
        "commenttext": "Yet another comment",
        "parentdocumentid": "c88cbdd6d05811e19fe912314301329d",
        "doctype": "comment",
        "topleveldocumentid": "c88cbdd6d05811e19fe912314301329d",
        "createdtime": 1343297245,
        "documentid": "b2d9f0f0d70911e1903d12314301329d"
    },
    {
        "commenttext": "I have a comment",
        "parentdocumentid": "c88cbdd6d05811e19fe912314301329d",
        "doctype": "comment",
        "topleveldocumentid": "c88cbdd6d05811e19fe912314301329d",
        "createdtime": 1343364418,
        "documentid": "1971ca6cd7a611e180fa12314301329d"
    }
]
```

EDIT:
Following comments, I have more specific questions:
Specifically, my questions are:

1: Is this JSON data structure a linked list?" (i.e. each item specifies its parent)

2: Is there a well known algorithm for iterating through a linked list and displaying it as sorted comment hierarchy? If yes, can someone direct me to a description?

3: Is a comment hierarchy a synonym for an "ordered tree"?

thanks

Comment: Question is too broad, not a good fit for SO. You'll get more answers by narrowing your question. Which part are you having trouble with? Need a templating library? How to handle nested comments? What have you tried? Right now the question looks like, please do my work for me!

Answer (score -1):

Use the underscore library for templates, and a `for ... in` loop to loop through each object (comment) in your array.

Here is a mockup of the basic pattern you should follow using this method:

```
var data = {...your json obj...},
    markup = $("#tmpl").html(),
    commentTmpl = _.template(markup);

for (comment in data) {
    $("#comment-list").append( commentTmpl(comment) );
}
```

And your template:

```
<script type="javascript/template">
    <li><%= commenttext %></li>
</script>
```

**Read these to learn:**

- Backbone template documentation: http://underscorejs.org/#template
- jQuery documentation: http://jQuery.com (use the search function to learn about *any* jQuery method)

Comment: Thanks.  I can't see how this solution organises the comments into a hierarchy with most recent first.

Comment: You would need to make use of javascripts `Array.sort()` method

Comment: That only works for a single level comment thread (like stackoverflow) rather than a hierarchy ( like hacker news).

Comment: Hmmm... do you have control over the output of this json?

Comment: Ideally, each comment should have a `collection` of subcomments, this is what you will need to ultimately need to turn your json into, on either the server side or client side... ill write up an example now

Comment: Given that each comment contains its date of creation and the documentid of its parent, it should not be necessary to modify the structure in order to generate a hierarchy - all required information is present.

Comment: Right, i'm talking about the method that would be most efficient... it may not be neccessary, but it is the most efficient.

Comment: I'm just looking for a way to do it at all using the existing structure.  Efficiency is not so important.